# Getting proper list of members from pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to get a list of all members in a replica set using pymongo.

```
import pymongo
conn = pymongo.Connection(replicaset='myreplica')
conf = conn.local.system.replset.find_one()
print conf['members']
```

This appears to work in one environment I have, returning a list of results as I would expect.

```
>>> print conf['members']
[{u'host': u'srvr-01:27017', u'_id': 0}, {u'priority': 0.5, u'host': u'srvr-02:27017', u'_id': 1}, {u'priority': 0.5, u'host': u'srvr-03:27017', u'_id': 2}]
>>>
```

However, in another environment, all I get returned is

```
>>> print conf['members']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'members'
>>> print conf
{u'_id': ObjectId('5483f1963784952946e3e799')}
>>>
```

I cannot figure out why the same code would return different results.  Environments are a copy of each other as far as I can tell.  The same replica set exists in both environments.

Anyone know why I am getting an OjbectID returned instead of a proper dictionary of results?  Thanks

Comment: Could it be possible that there is actually an empty entry like that? What happens when you run a find() instead of find_one()?

Comment: Hmm, yeah, I get some results.

    {u'_id': ObjectId('5483f1963784952946e3e799')}
    {u'_id': ObjectId('5483f1b13784952946e3e79c')}
    {u'_id': ObjectId('5483f1dd3784952946e3e79f')}
    ....
    {u'_id': ObjectId('5485844a3784952946e3e7bf')}
    {u'_id': u'rsdaas', u'version': 5, u'members': [{u'host': u'srvr-01:27017', u'_id': 0}, {u'priority': 0.5, u'host': u'srvr-02:27017', u'_id': 1}, {u'priority': 0.5, u'host': u'srvr-03:27017', u'_id': 2}]}

What are all the empty ones?  Guess I need to use find() and some more logic.

Comment: I do not know. I'm not familiar with your environment, so I can't really say for certain, sorry.

Comment: Do you know the best filter to apply to find() that would yield the list of members?

Comment: How about collection.find( { members : { $exists : true } } );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per our discussion, most likely the issue is that there are empty records that were inserted. I do not know how that came about, but you can try this to find only those records with members:

```
collection.find( { members : { $exists : true } } );
```